# Phd in the computer science - mathematics interface

Tags: phd, mathematics, computer-science, science, statistics

Currently I am Bachelor student in Psychology. My plan is to do a Master in Artificial-intelligence. And then I wish to do research on the interface in Computer Science/Artificial-intelligence and Mathematics. Is is possible to do a Phd in the Computer Science/Artificial-intelligence - Mathematics interface?

Comment: By “interface,” do you mean the interaction between math and CS? Or do you mean the waythe user interacts with the computer?

Comment: I mean mathematical solutions for AI/Computer Science problems

Comment: Can you rephrase that in different words? I don’t feel like I understand what you’re after

Comment: So I want to do mathematical research which js applied to Computer Science/Artificial intelligence

Comment: Ah I understand now! I also edited the last bit of your question out, as we strictly disallow questions about recommendations for programs or universities on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly do a PhD in mathematics and apply it to AI. You should also look at CS PhDs in addition to mathematics ones, as the boundary between the fields is pretty nebulous and which department will have the faculty you wish to work with will vary by the university. You should in particular look for university with a strong program in Combinatorics, Algorithms, and Topology (especially if you want to go into object recognition/computer vision).

Comment: With a degree in Psychology? I think you're giving OP false hopes.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Psychology can be a very computationally heavy field, and I know several people with psych backgrounds who have moved into AI. In any event, the question is if there are math PhDs that can be applied to AI, not if the OP is likely to be good at it.